# BX-slider double fade

Tags: bxslider

The slideshows on my homepage have a double fade transition. The new slide appears, disappears and appears again. I don't see the cause of this.

See: http://www.rodericklloyd.com

A slide on another page with (in my opinion) the same settings doesn't has this issue:

http://www.rodericklloyd.com/nl/showroom/all-art-galleries

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a conflict on your home page which isn't there on the inner pages.

If you remove this line from your home page then you remove the conflict:

```
<div style="display:none">website_monitor_hestec</div>
```